# Stack around the variable "carry" was corrupted

Tags: c

The following is a simple function which adds two 15-digit numbers together, both stored using 2 arrays of characters. However, after debugging, I am given this error: Run-Time Check Failure #2:  Stack around the variable "carry" was corrupted.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){

addition1();

getchar();
getchar();
return 0;
}

int addition1(){
    char numberArray1[16] = {4,5,9,2,7,4,9,5,7,1,6,2,0,3,0};
    char numberArray2[16] = {0,0,2,7,9,9,8,7,2,5,6,1,0,3,0};
    char str[5];
    char finalAnswer[16];
    int c, c1, c2, c3, answer = 0, a;
    int carry[25];

    //Displaying number 1
    for (c = 0; c < 15; c++){
        printf("%d" , numberArray1[c]);
    }

    printf(" + ");

    //Displaying number 2
    for(c1 = 0; c1 < 16; c1++){
        printf("%d" , numberArray2[c1]);
    }

    //Addition of the 2 numbers
    carry[14] = 0;

    for(c2 = 14; c2 >= 0; c2--){
        answer = carry[c2] + numberArray1[c2] + numberArray2[c2];

        if (answer <= 9){
            finalAnswer[c2] = answer;
            carry[c2-1] = 0;    
        } 
        else{
            carry[c2-1] = answer / 10;
            a = answer % 10;
            finalAnswer[c2] = a;                        
        }
    }

    printf("  =  ");

    for (c3 = 0; c3 <= 14; c3++){
        printf("%d" , finalAnswer[c3]);
    }

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Can someone please specify what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your indexing variable `c2` goes down to zero. So accessing via `carry[c2 - 1]` is invalid.

Comment: after solving the above problem, I am now being given this error: Run-Time Check Failure #2: Stack around the variable 'finalAnswer' war corrupted.